# Does ignoring a base type in Entity Framework Code First also ignore subclasses?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-6.1

I'm attempting to simulate a scenario in which I am inheriting from concrete base classes in a 3rd party library, then mapping my own classes using Entity Framework Code First. I would really prefer for my classes to have the same simple name as the base classes. I obviously can't change the class names of the base classes, nor can I change the base class to abstract. As expected, I get the following error:

> The type 'EfInheritanceTest.Models.Order' and the type
>   'EfInheritanceTest.Models.Base.Order' both have the same simple name
>   of 'Order' and so cannot be used in the same model. All types in a
>   given model must have unique simple names. Use 'NotMappedAttribute' or
>   call Ignore in the Code First fluent API to explicitly exclude a
>   property or type from the model.

As I understand it, in EF6 this is possible so long as only one of the classes is actually mapped. However, if I attempt to ignore the base class using the fluent API, I get the following error instead:

> The type 'EfInheritanceTest.Models.Order' was not mapped. Check that
>   the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method
>   or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was
>   defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does not inherit
>   from EntityObject.

... which seems to indicate that by ignoring the base class, I ignore any subclasses as well. Full code below. Any way to work around this and "unignore" the subclass? Or is this a limitation of EF type mapping?

```
namespace EfInheritanceTest.Models.Base
{
    public class Order
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal Amount { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace EfInheritanceTest.Models
{
    public class Order : Base.Order
    {
        public virtual DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace EfInheritanceTest.Data
{
    public class OrdersDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public OrdersDbContext() : base ("OrdersDbContext") { }

        public IDbSet<EfInheritanceTest.Models.Order> Orders { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Types<Models.Base.Order>().Configure(c => c.Ignore());
            modelBuilder.Types<Models.Order>().Configure(c => c.ToTable("order"));
            modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Order>().Map(c =>
                                                    {
                                                        c.MapInheritedProperties();
                                                        c.ToTable("order");
                                                    });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make the base class abstract?

Comment: I should add that when I make an EF project, I almost always have a base abstract class with an int Id property to be used as my primary key so I know it can be done. I don't use the fluent API though.

Comment: In the scenario I am simulating, base class is in the 3rd party lib that I can't change.

Comment: I've just grabbed one of my older projects and removed the abstract property from my class and it still worked. However, if I added the model builder ignore code, I got the same error as you.

Comment: If you are adding the Ignore, you may need to not call `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);`. Seems to work for me.

Comment: I removed the base call and I still get the error -- are you saying you don't get the "not mapped" error if you have the `Ignore` w/ no call to `base.OnModelCreating`?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit late, anyway: I was able to solve the issue with very simple configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<MyBaseClass>();
```

So EF don't care about MyBaseClass at all, but works with MyInheritedClass as it is not. Perfect!

The second error was related to:

```
 modelBuilder.Types<Models.Base.Order>().Configure(c => c.Ignore());
```

as you excluded both classes from EF mapping (it excludes all hierarchy from Models.Base.Order).

There is also an excellent post on [EF inheritance mapping](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this will work if the child class has the same name as the parent class.  I've definitely done this where the derived class has a different name than the parent class, but I doesn't look like this is possible when the names are the same (which I didn't know before).  To test it, I took one of my projects where the inheritance was working with EF and I changed the names to fit the naming scheme that you have above and I'm getting the same errors that you list.  It looks like this might be a limitation of the EF type mapping.  Are you able to change the name of your derived class to be different than the parent?